# Colorbar only shows one color in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder, colorbar

Within my B.Sc. thesis I have to investigate the distribution of pore pressure and stresses around a fluid-injecting well. I try to solve this part by using Spyder, which seems to be the best interface for me because I have nearly zero experience in coding.

Although I worked through the most important Python and matplotlib documentation I cant find the solution for my problem.

First here's my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Oct 01 10:26:29 2014

@author: Alexander
"""

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from matplotlib import cm
from math import *
from scipy.special import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

q = 6.0/1000                                    
rhof = 1000                                    
lameu = 11.2*10**9                              
lame = 8.4*10**9                               
pi                                             
alpha = 0.8                                     
G = 8.4*10**9                                   
k = 4*10**(-14)                                  
eta = 0.001                                                 
t = 10*365*24*3600                              

kappa = k/eta                                 
print "kappa ist:",kappa                                        
c = ((kappa*(lameu-lame)*(lame+2*G))/((alpha**2)*(lameu+2*G)))  
print "c ist:",c                                                

xmin = -10
xmax = 10
ymin = -10
ymax = 10

X = np.arange(xmin,xmax,0.5)
Y = np.arange(ymin,ymax,0.5)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

r=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)                                  
P=(q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,(r**2)/(4*c*t)))      
print x,y                                           
print P                                              
z = P/1000000                                   

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0,
                   antialiased=True)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)      
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)      

ax.set_title('Druckverteilung')
ax.set_xlabel('Distanz zu Well [m]')
ax.set_ylabel('Distanz zu Well [m]')
ax.set_zlabel('Druck in [MPa]')

plt.show()
```

I have two major questions:

1. After plotting, my colorbar only shows 1 color (blue) and I don't know why. I looked up for similar problems on this site, yet wasn't able to find a proper solution. How can I get this done?
2. Let's say I want to know the value of the pressure in my coordinates `x=5m` and `y=2m` from my injection point (x,y=0). Is there a code to "grab" this value?

---

I will try to plot some stresses (e.g. normal stress and shear stress) around a borehole. Can I avoid the error I encountered within the pressure in future plots by simply using your suggested proposition of

```
z[z == np.inf] = np.nan
```

and modifying the plot_surface command? I ask because I'm not sure if I will have a value within `inf`.

Comment: My solution will work even if there are no inf values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color scale is all blue because one of you z values in inf.  You can correct this first by setting the inf values in z to nan:

```
z[z == np.inf] = np.nan
```

And then telling [plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html) what range of values to plot using the vmin and vmax arguments:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0,
                   antialiased=True, vmin=np.nanmin(z), vmax=np.nanmax(z))
```

[image: surface plot with reasonable color scale]

You can easily create a [function](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html) to calculate z for a give x and y like this:

```
def calcZ(x,y):
    r=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)                                  
    P=(q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,(r**2)/(4*c*t)))                                                                                              
    z = P/1000000  
    return z
```

Comment: Simul-post! I think Molly's solution is better. Using interpolate functions--as I suggested--gives `NaN`'s and `Inf`'s in the neighborhood of 0. Molly's option doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, if you add `vmin=0.15, vmax=0.24` to your `ax.plot_surface` call, you will get a colored plot. I don't know why plot_surface doesn't do a better job of auto-selecting these color limits, but I guess it doesn't.

Regarding your second question, if you want to be able to grab arbitrary points (not necessarily the ones in your grid), you can use an interpolate function. For example, first create an interpolator function:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
intrp = interp2d(X, Y, z)
```

Then you can use that to calculate values wherever you like. You can get a single point:

```
a_single_point = intrp(2, 4)
```

Or a line of points from x=-3 to -1, along y=2:

```
vals = intrp(np.arange(-3, -1, .1), 2)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you farenorth for your furthergoing suggestions!